# Anyone know of a good free patch creator?

Tags: patch

Does anyone know of a good patching program that is free? You know, one that can take a directory with your old program in it and compare it to a directory with your new version, and spit out a patch that is only the difference between the two?

Also, I am looking for something that can patch the entire directory, not just one exe.

EDIT:
Thanks for the answers, but I am looking for an end user patch for product updates. Nothing to do with the source.

Comment: Your question is somewhat vague, do you mean the directories with the program *sources*, or the directories with the program *executable*?

Comment: Hi guys, I'm also looking for this. But I want something that can build **cross-platform** patches as well (Windows and Unix, mostly). ``bspatch`` and ``bsdiff`` could be the answer but I don't think it will work for my case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is [Binary patch and diff](http://www.daemonology.net/bsdiff/), which is free, Windows port available.

Comment: If you need a more end-user-friendly result you could wrap this in a standard setup package. Using for example Inno Setup and its scripting functionality it should be possible to compress several patches into a single installer, determine at runtime which patch to apply, create backups of the old executable, ...

Comment: bsdiff is easily the best solution for binary patching. Unfortunately, it's just a binary and doesn't offer anything for actually creating an installer or patcher.

Answer (score 2):

I've never used this but it is free. It might be worth a try:

[Patch Maker 1.2](http://www.clickteam.com/patch-maker).

Comment: This is nice, unfortunately, not cross-platform.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Subversion, [SmartSVN](https://www.smartsvn.com/) can create a patch for directories (recursive and all) for the files changed since the last commit. I understand this is only a partial answer and it's not CLI, but it's a really good tool if you deal with an SVN repo here.

[SmartSVN patch http://cdn.beerpla.net.lg1x3.simplecdn.net/for_www/screenshots/smartsvn-patch.gif](http://cdn.beerpla.net.lg1x3.simplecdn.net/for_www/screenshots/smartsvn-patch.gif)

Answer (score 0):

A list of tools [here](http://binary-patch.qarchive.org/) reveals a few marked as "free".

- [Dispatcher](http://puchisoft.com/dispatcher.php): will use an updater GUI as well. They have a quick demo video on their site.

Answer (score 0):

The best tool I've seen for this purpose is Visual Patch 3.5 . It provides the same functionality that you've mentioned. Although it needs to be purchased since it's not free software.

Comment: Why is it the best? And do you have any affiliation with the producers?

Comment: It is best since I used it for the same purpose as mentioned in the question asked and it is very easy to use and no, I do not any affiliation with the producers.